# Vsvim escape key rebinding

Tags: vim, visual-studio-2015, vsvim

How I can rebind escape key in vsvim (in Visual Studio 2015)? Now, I use <kbd>esc</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> to enter command mode, but I want to use `df` keys instead. How I can rebind them?
I find out that I need to create `.vsvimrc` file in my HOME directory and write there some command similar to `nmap <df> :vsc MyCommand`. Is it right?
But I don't understand what exactly command must be instead "MyCommand".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do need a `.vimrc` file. On a mac or linux computer it would go in your home directory. I'm guessing from your question that you might be on Windows. A brief google search indicates that the HOME directory on Windows is also probably right. If you want to check for sure, open vim, type `:echo $HOME`, and press enter. It will print the file path. Also, on Windows this file should be called `_vimrc`.

Once you've created your vimrc file include this line

```
inoremap df <esc>
```

You'll have to close vim and reopen it for the command work.

Comment: Actually to learn file folder use `:set vimrcpaths?` in visual studio. After creating/changing file and restarting studio check loaded file with `:set vimrc?`

Comment: I had to use `<Esc>` instead of `<esc>` for it to work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I looked for this line: `inoremap df <esc>`, because I use "escape" or "ctrl + [" to enter command mode from input mode.

Comment: Absolutely right - silly mistake on my part. My answer should have read `inoremap`. I've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio VsVim on Mac, there is an option in settings:

Menu: `Visual Studio > Preferences > Other > Vim Settings`

I use `jk` in the `Insert mode escape binding` option and it works well. The `.vimrc` change did not work for me but given this setting in the GUI, I did not further investigate why my `rc` file wasn't being respected.